# Как создать временный файл с конкретным именем в python3 с помощью tempfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как с помощью библиотеки tempfile создать временный файл, но с конкретным именем? В `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` нет такого атрибута.

Comment: По сути весь смысл модуля tempfile - в создании файла со случайным именем. Если нужно создать файл с конкретным именем - просто создайте его с помощью open, потом удалите.

Comment: А зачем, если не секрет?